# display a div over a div with display property table-row

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to put some data in tabular format. I want to put data in divs but also formatted, so I used display:table-row on div. Also I want to be able to show a div(`<div class='hover'>`) with options over table-row div(`<div class='row'>`) when someone hovers over it.

#### CSS

```
.table {
width: 100%;
display: table;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
.row {
width: 100%;
display: table-row;
}
.column {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.hover {
width: 100%;
display: none;
z-index: 5;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
background-color: #fff;
opacity: 0.3;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='column'>ID</div>
        <div class='column'>Room</div>
        <div class='column'>Name</div>
        <div class='column'>Photo</div>
        <div class='column'>Deposit Money</div>
        <div class='column'>Balance</div>
    </div>
    <div class='row content'>
        <div class='hover'></div>
        <div class='column'>".$row['id']."</div>
        <div class='column'>".$row['room']."</div>
        <div class='column'>".$row['name']."</div>
        <div class='column'><img src='' width='80' height='80'></div>
        <div class='column'>".$row['total']."</div>
        <div class='column'>".$row['current']."</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('.content').bind({
                mouseenter: function(){
                    $('.hover').each(function(){
                        $(this).show();
                    });
                },
                mouseleave: function() {
                    $('.hover').each(function(){
                        $(this).hide();
                    });
                }
            });
```

The problem is when I hover over `<div class='row'>` , `<div class='hover'>`
appears but it shifts all the elements in row by one cell.
Please help me.

Comment: It's the third time I answer this today. **YOU CANNOT POSITION ELEMENTS ABSOLUTELY INSIDE TABLE-CELLS.** This is true also for elements that *are* not table-cells, but have `display: table-cell` and thus *behave* like table-cells. **Content in a table-cell cannot "leave" the cell by any CSS means.**

Comment: Please suggest an alternative, how to remain data formatted but show a div over this for options.

Comment: Stop mimicking a table with CSS, and neither use a real table.

Comment: The other problem your code has that `<div class="hide">` does not have `display: table-cell`, but since its parent has `display: table-row;` the browser is invited to interpret `<div class="hide">` as if it were a table-cell.

Comment: Why are you not using a real HTML `<table>` in the first place? Because someone told you that "you don't use tables any more these days"?

Comment: That's not what I was thinking but, I used table in first place but it threw away the `<div class='hover'>` out of table

Comment: You will have to make it a `<tr class="hover"><td colspan="6">...</td></tr>` in a real table, but that *only works on a **real** table* because with `divs` you cannot use `colspan` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of CSS Tables, perhaps `flexbox` which allows this kind of interaction.

```js
$('.content').bind({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $('.hover').each(function() {
      $(this).show();
    });
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('.hover').each(function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:  center;
}

.row.header .column {
  border:1px solid lightblue;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
  padding: 1em;
}

.row.content .column {
  border:1px solid lightgreen;
  background: #bada55;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}

.hover {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='table'>
      <div class='row header'>
        <div class='column'>ID</div>
        <div class='column'>Room</div>
        <div class='column'>Name</div>
        <div class='column'>Photo</div>
        <div class='column'>Deposit Money</div>
        <div class='column'>Balance</div>
    </div>
    <div class='row content'>
        <div class='hover'> I'M AN OVERLAY</div>
        <div class='column'>ID</div>
        <div class='column'>ROOM</div>
        <div class='column'>NAME</div>
        <div class='column'><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-80-80-6.jpg"/></div>
        <div class='column'>TOTAL</div>
        <div class='column'>CURRENT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/JdzVxY)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me :)